# random circle with radius r on cartesian plane, probability of it not cutting x and y axis with intercepts.

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, geometry, probability-theory, geometric-probability

I have a tough question here. Choose a circular disk of radius r on the cartesian plane. What's the probability it is not cut by horizontal lines with integer y intercept, or vertical lines with integer x intercept? I have no clue what to do. just so you know this is not homework, it is just a problem I found in the the book while studying for my next test.

Comment: What do you mean by "dropping a circular disk on the cartesian plane"? If I drop it in a deterministic way, the probability might be $0$ or $1$.

Comment: I think it's probably: choose a random circle of radius r in the plane. What's the probability it is not cut by horizontal lines with integer y intercept, or vertical lines with integer x intercept

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a deterministic way. I modified the question so you can understand it.

Comment: Please define "put" more clearly.  How is this disk "put" onto the plane?

Comment: I defined it better. I changed the post accordingly. Use aaa's question in the comments, it should yield the same result.

Comment: What does: "choose a random circle of radius r in the plane." mean? This is very important, although it might seem a dull question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a more elementary method, try this. For a fixed $r$, if $r>1/2$, the probability is 0 (the circle will certainly intersect one of the lines). Now, suppose you fixed $0<r<1$. Then, choosing the circle is equivalent to choosing its center. Consider every square in the plane with vertices $(n,m), (n+1,m), (n+1,m+1), (n, m+1), n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$. If you pick a point in a certain square, there is only a certain region inside which the circle will not cut the lines (which, in this case, are the borders of the square). It's easy to see that the allowable region in this case is a square of side $1-2r$. If you were to pick a point only inside the square, the probability would be the ratio of the areas of the squares: $(1-2r)^2$.

But you have to pick a point in the plane. The intuitive idea is that the ratio of the areas is preserved no matter how many squares you pick, and should be generalizable to the whole plane. The formal way to proceed, though, would probably to construct an equivalence relation between points, under which two points are equivalent iff they are corresponding points from different squares (i.e. the both are centers of some square). You would then have a new, special square, which behaves exactly as I said before (but is, actually, only the collection of all classes of equivalence). You can now proceed as before.

By this argument, the probability is $(1-2r)^2$. I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: Observe that, although there exists a uniform distribution on each unit square, there exists no such thing as a "uniform distribution on the plane". That is why the problem is, in principle, ill posed.

Comment: Yes. I do think, though, the closer you can get to defining a valid probability (rather, a valid problem), is by considering the collection $\mathbb{R}^2 / \sim$,  instead of each unit square.

Comment: very helpful but how did you get those vertices

Answer (score 1):

Call the centre of circle be $(U,V)$. If $U$ is not within $x\pm r$ and $V$ is not within $y\pm r$, then the circle will not cut the two lines.

Depending on how you "select" a circle, if the joint probability density function of $U$ and $V$ is $f_{U,V}(u,v)$, then the probability is

$$\begin{align*}
&\Pr(\text{Circle does not cut the lines})\\
=& \int_{-\infty}^{x-r}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{y-r}f_{U,V}(u,v)\ dv + \int_{y+r}^{+\infty}f_{U,V}(u,v)\ dv\right]\ du
+\int_{x+r}^{+\infty}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{y-r}f_{U,V}(u,v)\ dv + \int_{y+r}^{+\infty}f_{U,V}(u,v)\ dv\right]\ du
\end{align*}$$

Comment: I can't use integrals or derivatives yet.